# writing to HDFS via multi threading vs using options like hbase / hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs

I need to bulk write to the hadoop system using a JAVA API, in an efficient way.
Just checking the options here.

Is writing to HDFS via multi threading an expensive operation compared to using options like hbase / hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive and HBase are 2 different tools. Hbase is a database and Hive is a query engine. Hbase is different from hive and hadoop.

Now answering your question you can write to HDfS using mapreduce with Java API and If your program is very efficient with respect to data you are processing. Then map reduce can be faster then hive. 
The major reason for this is the fact that whatever query you write in hive get converted into map reduce program. So in the end  it's the efficiency of mapreduce program which matters.Thus if you can write an better and  efficient program then it can be faster then hive query.

Comment: thanks @siddhartha for the response, will try to optimize the multi threaded threaded program with JAVA API

Answer (score -1):

One thing before answering the question, I think you are a little confused on the concepts.

> Hadoop: MapReduce + HDFS (Distributed file System).

**Hive** is just a layer on top of HDFS. It's not a FileSystem at all. Does not make sense to compare HDFS with Hive.

**HBase** is a non-relational database that can run on top of Hadoop and provides you random data access/querying capabilities. HDFS, by itself has no support for reads/writes at random location.

Quoting from **Hadoop - The Definitive Guide**:

> HDFS is built around the idea that the most efficient data processing
>   pattern is a write-once, read-many-times pattern. A dataset is
>   typically generated or copied from source, and then various analyses
>   are performed on that dataset over time. Each analysis will involve a
>   large proportion, if not all, of the dataset, so the time to read the
>   whole dataset is more important than the latency in reading the first
>   record.

I think this article ([Introduction to Hadoop HDFS](https://www.edureka.co/blog/introduction-to-apache-hadoop-hdfs/)) will be very helpful you.

To go a little further and trying to answer your question, HBase stores data as key/value pairs as in a column database. You can think about Hbase as an extension for the Hadoop environment that allows you to quickly read/write data.It stores the data in the HDFS.

Some features:

1. Low latency access to small amounts of data from within a large data set. You can access single rows quickly from a billion row table.
2. Flexible data model to work with and data is indexed by the row key.
3. Fast scans across tables.

**4. Scale in terms of writes as well as total volume of data.**